# How use local environment variable with Vagrant?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, vagrantfile

I'm passing my local environment variables like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |de|

  de.vm.box = 'ubuntu/trusty64'
  de.vm.hostname = 'virtual_machine'
  de.vm.network 'public_network', bridge:ENV['NETWORK_INTERFACE'], ip:'192.168.2.170'

  de.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 2
  end

  de.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled:true
  de.vm.synced_folder '../../synced/shared/', '/shared/'
  de.vm.synced_folder '../../synced/devops/', '/devops/'

  install = ENV['DEVOPS_HOME'] + '/vagrant/lib/install'
  de.vm.provision 'shell', path: install + '/basic'
  de.vm.provision 'shell', path: install + '/java8', args: ['automatic']
  de.vm.provision 'shell', path: install + '/aws_cli', args: [ENV['S3_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],ENV['S3_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']]

  setup = ENV['DEVOPS_HOME'] + '/vagrant/lib/setup'
  de.vm.provision 'shell', path: setup + '/hosts'

  sys = ENV['DEVOPS_HOME'] + '/vagrant/lib/system'
  de.vm.provision 'shell', path: sys + '/add_user', args: ['virtual-machine',ENV['VIRTUAL_MACHINE_PASSWORD']]

  steps = ENV['DEVOPS_HOME'] + '/vagrant/server/virtual_machine/steps'
  de.vm.provision 'shell', path: steps + '/install_rserve'

end
```

Obviously, for that I need to set this variable on my `~/.profile` file. But I wonder if there is another way of doing this. Where I don't need to inform this via `Vagrantfile`, it doesn't look nice.

Comment: its one way to work - another solution if you distribute the box is to add those variables into a yaml file (for example, son would work as any other file) and read file into your Vagrantfile, so you don't need to set the variables into your bash.

Comment: Do you have any link explaining this approach Frédéric ? It seems very interesting. Btw, I won't distribute my boxes, for now at least :)

Comment: showing an example of my setting in an answer for visibility. don't really have link as I've made up myself and through different reading but none particular, in fact I came on this from using puppet and hiera so I share the same file (don't know if its good or bad but I find it convenient)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one way I manage to have settings dependency is to use an external file (I use yaml, but any file would work like json .... Vagrantfile is a ruby script so as long as you can easily read it using ruby you're fine)

An example of my Vagrantfile using a Yaml dependency

```
:# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'yaml'
settings = YAML.load_file 'settings/common.yaml'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = settings['host_box'] || "pws/centos65"
  config.ssh.username = settings['ssh_user']

  config.vm.define "db" do |db|
    db.vm.hostname = settings['db_hostname']
    db.vm.network "private_network", ip: settings['host_db_address']
  end

...

end
```

the file `settings/common.yaml` would be defined as

```
--- 
host_db_address:  "192.168.90.51" 
host_app_address: "192.168.90.52"

db_hostname:      "local.db"

ssh_user:         "pws"
```

As said in comment, the main advantage I found using this technique is when you distribute box. My team would git clone the project, has to fill up the settings (for password dependency and so on) and ready to go.

Comment: That's a great solutions Frédéric! Thank you for sharing! :)

Comment: Beautiful answer

Comment: Great approach. By using separate YAML files for sensitive vs. non-sensitive data and adding the former to `.gitignore` a nice Vagrant convention can be established.